# Adding empty line between paragraphs with VIM

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a single command to turn this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur.
>  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
>  Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. 
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

into this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur.
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur.
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it wrapped or not ?

Comment: @yakiang Sorry, what's wrapped?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it well.. maybe you could have a look at [this](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-lines-text-display-dont-wrap-vi-vim-editor)

Comment: @yakiang I guess it's wrapped.

Comment: @alexchenco In that case, see http://superuser.com/a/592508 — it may be what you’re looking for.

Comment: @ebenezer ...you're telling him the same site I suggested at my answer. - -

Comment: Oops. Well I did upvote your answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's wrapped, that means a `paragraph` is actually only `ONE` line,  and you're actually adding a single blank line between lines.  try:

`:g/.\n\n\@!/norm o`

It's explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/592503/vim-adding-empty-line-between-lines) .
And if it's not wrapped (means there're many lines in ONE paragraph), I've no idea how to do it, either. But according to the explaination of that site, you can try to manage it by writing your own regex rules !

Comment: If it’s not wrapped, what separates two paragraphs? :)

Comment: I've no idea, either. Actually I think it's difficult to tell from two paragraphs...

Comment: Vim golf: `:g/.\n\n\@!/pu_`

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\.\s*\n\(\S\)/\.\r\r\1
```

Obtains the desired result with the given sample (which contains a pesky trailing space).

We search for a dot followed by zero or more whitespace characters (because of the pesky trailing space), followed by a newline, followed by a non-whitespace character that we capture.

We replace with a dot, followed by two newlines and the non-whitespace character that we captured earlier.

(edit)

The following substitution is more generic and suits your non-specified requirements:

- it doesn't care about how each "paragraph" ends
- it respects indenting as well

so…

```
:%s/\s*\n\(\s*\S\)/\r\r\1
```

If you want to normalize your buffer and remove indenting:

```
:%s/\s*\n\(\s*\)\(\S\)/\r\r\2
```

or, with less backslashes…

```
:%s/\v\s*\n(\s*)(\S)/\r\r\2
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work when a paragraph ends with a quotation mark.

Comment: @alexchenco, it works with your sample. If you have special requirements, put them into your question.